# How to submit PR with changes to JSON file src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json in where?

Tags: token, solana

I am going to set token symbol and name, icon on solana network.
[I checked this link for that.](https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list)

There was written like that.
`Submit PR with changes to JSON file src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json. Please follow the Uniswap Token List specification found here: https://github.com/Uniswap/token-lists`

I want to know the way more details.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at one of the other pull requests in the repo, it'll give you more information about what changes to make.  Here's an example: https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/pull/1167

In it, it says:

```
Please include change to the src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json file in the PR.
DON'T modify any other token on the list.

At minimum each entry should have

    Token Address:
    Token Name:
    Token Symbol:
    Logo: (logo should be uploaded under assets/mainnet//*.<png/svg>)
    Link to the official homepage of token:
    Coingecko ID if available (https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3#/coins/get_coins__id_):
```

If you need more information about how to submit a pull request through GitHub, check out their documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests